# Process blocking when using rosbags and rate sleep

Tags: ros, rosbag, sleep, clock

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi !

I'm launching a rosbag file from a launch. At the start of the launch I have:

```
  <param name="/use_sim_time" value="True"/>
```

then I call the rosbag as:

```
   <node pkg="rosbag" type="rosbag" name="rosbag"
         args="play --clock /home/andreu/rosbags/platformLaserFME.bag" />`
```

Finnally I call the node that I'm debugging:

```
   <node pkg="localization3d_node" type="localization3d_node" 
         name="localization3d_node"
         args="" output="screen"/>`
```

In my node localization3d_node, the mainThread() is just as follows:

```
  {
    this->myStuff();
    this->loop_rate_.sleep();
  }
```

where `loop_rate_` is a `ros::Rate` type variable.

And at the localization3d_node constructor I set:

```
this->loop_rate_ = 5;//in [Hz]
```

So, the issue appears at execution: my node gets blocked since it executes the myStuff() function only once and then it stops sleeping for ever.

Observation: I recorded the rosbag also with the clock topic, so I don't see any difference in terms of published topics when I call rosbag play with/without the --clock option.

The question is: what I'm doing wrong to block my process ?

Thanks for your answers !!

Andreu

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10831/process-blocking-when-using-rosbags-and-rate-sleep/) by [Andreu](https://answers.ros.org/users/932/andreu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 169 on 2011-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Rate.sleep() method will just sleep for the rest of the period.

You need to put it inside a for loop or while loop in your code if you want myStuff to be called multiple times.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-08-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1